# How to make an executable command like 'ls'

Tags: command-line, ls, bin-folder

i am new to linux and is fascinated how the command in the linux works.
i want to make my own command to do such things. like call my command 'info' that gives me information about the files.

Comment: IMHO being new use existing tools unless you are planning on becoming a linux architecture expert                                                                                stat <file> for example